# Jquery, How to unselect all radio button in radio group

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors

Anyone know how to unselect all radio buttons in a radio group ?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="emptimfields">
              <label id="lbl_emptim">How regulary do you employ people to help cultivate your land? </label><br/><br/>

             <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical" id="emptim">

              <input name="emptim" id="radio1" value="fromtimetotime" type="radio" openmrs-valuecoded="" />
              <label for="radio1"> From time to time </label>

              <input name="emptim" id="radio2" value="allthetime" type="radio" openmrs-valuecoded="" />
              <label for="radio2">All the time</label>

              <input name="emptim" id="radio3" value="dontknow" type="radio" openmrs-valuecoded="" />
              <label for="radio3"> Don't know </label> 
            </fieldset>
        </div>
```

**JQuery side:**

```
$('input:radio[name=emptim]:checked').prop('checked', false); // doesn't work
```

I'm certainly missing something basic, but I can't figure out what is the problem.

First, I check Yes and then check a value of the second radio group :

[image]

Then, I check No to hide the second radio group:

[image]

Then, If I click on next, I get the value of what I've checked (but I checked no previously, so here I don't want an alert, I want the radioButton "From time to time" to be unchecked) :

[image]

Finally, if I come back, nothing happend :

[image]

Comment: Always suspect the selector. Does `$('input:radio[name=emptim]:checked')` definitely find the elements?

Comment: Works here http://jsfiddle.net/NFtVm/ (chrome beta)

Comment: Yes, if i do alert($('input:radio[name=emptim]:checked').val()); , I have the value of the radio button selected.

Comment: Works fine in FF too http://jsfiddle.net/szatc/1/

Comment: when are you executing this? on document load?

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. I'm using the version 1.7.1 of jQuery and version 1.1.0 of jQuery mobile

Comment: I'm executing this when I'm changing the pages. I will put screen shots, 2 seconds

Comment: Radio groups should always have exactly one member checked at any given time. The behaviour which allows none to be checked initially is there to support legacy pages. You should probably add a new "None of the above" radio button if you want that to be an option.

Comment: $('input[type=radio]:checked').prop('checked', false);

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You can give them a classname and try:

```
$('.classname').prop('checked', false);
```

When you use an older version of jQuery than 1.6 it has to be:

```
 $('<selector>').attr('checked', false);
```

**EDIT :**

Call the method `.checkboxradio("refresh");` has also worked for me.

Answer (score 23):

```
$('input:radio[name=indicatorType]').each(function () { $(this).prop('checked', false); });
```

Alternative solution for making 'unchecked' whole radio buttons of a radio group('indicatorType' for above code sample).

Answer (score 8):

This should do it. Notice the refresh option at the end to force the controlgroup to be updated.

An additional benefit of this method is that it targets a specific radio group by name, rather than all radio controls on a page.

```
$('input:radio[name=emptim]:checked').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Comment: @AlessandroLallo This IS a question about JQuery Mobile!!! Please check the question tags and remove the downvote. Thanks.

Comment: The title is irrelevent, the vast majority of posts do NOT mention the platform at all. The tags are the relevant details against which an answer should be formed.

Answer (score 0):

I made a non-display radio button and called that via my PHP. You could use jquery to select the hidden button. I couldn't get the solutions here working, so I used some PHP, as I had to call the value from the DB. To help anyone, the solution I used is:

```
<input type="radio" id="test" value="" class = "timescale" name="timescale_radio_buttons" style="display: none" <?php $x = ((empty($gigObject->getTimescale())) || ($gigObject->getTimescale() == 'Blank')) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; echo $x; ?>>
```

Answer (score -2):

The prop doesnt works for me, bu this works perfectly :

```
('input:radio[name="RadioName"]').each(function () { $(this).attr('checked', false); });
```